# Perforce: Move a changelist to P4Sandbox?

Tags: perforce

I have a changelist in Perforce that's grown to the point where I'd like to start making checkpoint commits (26 edits, 1 add). I don't want to commit to mainline, though, since the code isn't usable yet. I have P4Sandbox installed, but I haven't been using it: the changelist belongs to my client on the main depot. Is there a simple way to move the pending changelist to P4Sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of options.  First, you can use shelving as a way to save work-in-progress without using P4Sandbox.  You can shelve as many copies of your work-in-progress as you like.

Second, you can make a private branch (if the admins allow it).

Finally, if you do want to use P4Sandbox, you'll need to set up a new instance, then just manually copy your work-in-progress to the new P4Sandbox working area.

Comment: I'm already using shelve, but I'd like to have a history of the work in progress since I'm having to solve a few inter-related issues with this change. I was hoping for a less manual way to copy it to P4Sandbox than copying all the changed files, then running p4 edit or p4 add on each one as needed. For instance, to move uncommitted changes from one Mercurial repo to another, I'd create a patch file in one (hg diff) and apply it to the other (hg patch --no-commit).